# Correlation of transformed variables

Tags: regression, data-transformation, model

Let´s say I have two explanatory variables: `loan_amount` and `salary`. They aren´t normally distributed. So, I perform a natural logarithmic transformation on both and I create a new variable which is $\frac{loan\_amount}{salary}$ ratio.

Would it be correct to model regression with the 3 new created variables as explanatory ones? Or is it multicollinearity?

Comment: You don’t need explanatory variables to be normal. You don’t even need the response variable to be normal. When we talk about wanting “normal” distributions in regression, we mean that we want the residuals to have a normal distribution.